# Como inserir tecla de comando no c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Alguém poderia me ajudar, queria criar um comando com as teclas `CTRL` + `Z` ou algo do tipo para poder salvar, editar ou enviar dados, como forma de atalho para um botão criado no `Form`.

Comment: Windows forms??

Comment: Sim, Visual Studio.

Comment: A resposta atende o que foi pedido? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

1. Altere a propriedade [`KeyPreview`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview(v=vs.110).aspx) do *form* como **`true`**.
2. Defina as ações para os atalhos no evento [`KeyDown`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown(v=vs.110).aspx) do *form*

   Exemplo:

   ```
   private void MainForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Z)            
           Desfazer();            

       if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S)
           Salvar();            

       //Assim por diante
   }
   ```

Também é possível sobrescrever o método [`ProcessCmdKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx)

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData) 
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.S)) 
    {
        Salvar();
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção vou testar aqui.